How to use filter_poi() to filter for points between 1 and max height minus 3
I am trying to filter a normalized point cloud down to only those points 1 m above ground up to those 3 m below the canopy. How do I reference the tallest (Z max) point values?
Setup
library(lidR)

las.dir<- "E:\\FNF_LAS\\Batch5_FNF_4"
fileNames<- list.files(las.dir, pattern = "*216539.las|*217533.las|*217538.las", full.names = T)


las<- readLAS(fileNames[1])
las.norm<- normalize_height(las, algorithm = tin(), na.rm = T, res = 10)

This obviously doesn't work, but this is the sort of thing I'm trying to accomplish:
las.norm_minus3<- filter_poi(las.norm, Z > 1 & Z < (zmax - 3))


Welcome to Stackoverflow. What classes do you have available that might be used in normalize_height( x,  use_class = c(?, ?, ?, assuming a DEM isn't used? And max # of returns.?

@Chris - I'm using the default ground and water points as classes. Available classes also include highest hit, first of many and classes in between HH and Ground. Honestly, it hadn't crossed my mind to use a DEM, but that's an option

I think I may have just answered my own question:  las.norm_minus3<- filter_poi(las.norm, Z > 1 & Z < (max(Z) - 3)) appears to do the trick

I think the 'under canopy` (as I took the challenge) could be interpolated to an undulating surface using max(returns) and max(returns -1). You could use your singleton returns in place of DEM for ground + 1m,  then bracket as your z surface above -3. An approximation. But answer both ways, as you have the data. Then accept your answer (if it works...), or add further attempts (code) above with link to data.

I found a working solution for my needs:
filter_poi(las.norm, Z > 1 & Z < (max(Z) - 3))
This code filters the point cloud to display only those values between 1m from ground level and 3m below the highest point, as I was looking for.
I'm sure there are other answers, such as the solution proposed by @Chris in his second comment, but this one feels simpler for me.
